# BoxCutter and HardOps Bevel with Imported Mesh

Tags: modifiers, import, bevel

importing my mesh from C4d to blender in order to play with it using boxcutter and HOps innovative tools, wanted to isolate bevels for each new boolean operation I do, but I have a problem when importing the mesh, every time I use a bevel applied with HardOps it applies it to certain parts of the mesh and not only to the new boolean, given that I want to avoid using a bevel on my imported mesh and start using booleans operations directly and applying bevels on those booleans, keep in mind when creating a simple box everything works normally, but when importing a different mesh the same rules seem not to apply any suggestions? :D

Ps: The mesh in question was created originally in blender then imported into c4d, afterward i wanted to go back with it for further tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

HOps applies bevels based on certain rules using the Bevel modifier. Off the top of my head, I can't remember what it is by default, but you can choose from things like the angle of each edge, weight and vertex groups, just like you can if you were to adjust the modifier options.

By and large, HOps does not add anything new to Blender as such - it is a series of convenient shortcuts to aid and streamline the hard surface modelling workflow in many ways. This means that many of the options it plays with can be found and adjusted in vanilla Blender.

As for your particular case, you'll find that the new boolean modifiers you create are being placed at the bottom of the modifier stack, meaning they are applied last, meaning that your bevel does not process this new geometry because it's processed before the boolean is added. You can change the behaviour of HOps' modifier placement if you wish, but just bear this in mind. Learn more here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html

Move your bevel modifier to beneath your booleans in order for your newly cut shapes to be bevelled. Bear in mind that the bevel options are now applied globally to all edges based on the aforementioned rules. You can use vertex groups or the edge angle to hone it in a little bit if that helps or you may need to start making decisions about which bevels you want to manually add in a destructive way. Speaking from experience with HOps/BC :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your Replay, in my case it's not quite an order modifier thing on the hierarchy modifier stack, I just want to exclude my main Imported geometry from all modifiers and only applies bevels on the booleans modifiers, I used the Shift Ctrl option on Hardops that allow you to create a new bevel that will work on your next boolean operation, it works but not on all the mesh parts are affected and others are not, this is a bit detailed screenshots of whats is going on with my mesh ( https://ibb.co/Rc9V4ym )

Comment: @AkramFex, I see the problem. Vertex groups will fix it, but it's a bit cumbersome and would require destructive editing. Other than that, try adding the bevels to your boolean shape. Also a bit cumbersome, but you could edit your boolean cutters to look more like funnels or the heads of screws, and bevel the intermediate area so that this bevel then gets cut into the shape.

Hopefully this brief illustration I made helps explain what I'm trying to say: https://ibb.co/PN78fDZ

As you can see, you can customise the shape as you will. You can still use HOps to edit your cutters.

Comment: thank you very much, so the VortexGroupe did the job, I'm fairly new to blender and didn't know about vertex groups until now, the problem was fixed but one thing still counterintuitive is when you assign a vertex group to a bevel and afterward when adding a boolean operation that boolean will be stacked last on the hierarchy modifier stack, which means i have to go move that bevel manually so that it would be applied to my new boolean, before that the bevel would remain always last in the chain so that it affects all the boolean operation automatically, it would kill the speed workflow :(